# Chrono DateTime from u64 unix timestamp in Rust

Tags: datetime, rust, rust-chrono

How does one convert a u64 unix timestamp into a `DateTime<Utc>`?

```rust
let timestamp_u64 = 1657113606;
let date_time = ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many options.

Assuming we want a `chrono::DateTime`. The [offset page](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/struct.Utc.html) suggests:

> Using the TimeZone methods on the UTC struct is the preferred way to construct DateTime instances.

There is a TimeZone method [timestamp_opt](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/trait.TimeZone.html#method.timestamp_opt) we can use.

```rust
use chrono::{TimeZone, Utc};
    
let timestamp_u64 = 1657113606;
let date_time = Utc.timestamp_opt(timestamp_u64 as i64, 0).unwrap();
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c115e6d1e5e3740889ee8b4187ee23c7)

Comment: the answer only solves for i64 -> DateTime, not u64 like the question asked. An important nuance, since with u64 you have to account for extra precision.

Comment: You can either `as i64` or `.try_into().unwrap()` which is safe for unix timestamps unless you're working with timestamps billions of years into the future. I'll edit the answer to be for u64.